# How to Play Youtube video in webview in android?

Tags: android

I want to play a YouTube video in webview in android, which should not open in a new window. It should only play in webview on android.

Comment: Is there any control like webbrowser like C# winform can you use in android?
maybe you can use some control to make it.
I just know a little about android, hope this can help you.

Comment: Maybe this solution will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257389/youtube-video-not-showing-in-webview/7790908#7790908

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one, it works for me.

```
WebView video = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video);
String widthAndHeight = "width='220' height='200'";
String videoURL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/DZi6DEJsOJ0?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL";

String temp = "<object "+widthAndHeight+">" +
"<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>" +
"</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>" +
"</param><embed src='"+ videoURL +"'" +
" type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'" + widthAndHeight +
"></embed></object>";

video.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    video.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    video.loadData(temp,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Is not working, Only showing white screen and blue box. i.e. plugins unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Try Android Youtube Player API 
read more here : https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/