# youtube video not showing in webView

Tags: android, video, webview

I am new to android. Can anyone please tell how to play youtube video. My requirement is the video should display in the 'WebView' initially and on tapping that, the video should get played.

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
WebSettings websets = webView.getSettings(); 
websets.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
registerForContextMenu(webView); 
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/youtubes.html");
```

Comment: The most common way to do this would be to launch your own intent and use the YouTube application to display the video.You should check out the answers to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview

Comment: For those finding this question, I've outlined how to make your webview able to play youtube videos here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12850816/223440

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps, I came accross this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1/5439573#5439573)

And indeed, I basically only needed to add to the application manifest xml:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

And voila, even the youtube video's started playing

Only available from Android 3.0 (API level 11)

Comment: I guess you also have to have an device capable of hardware acceleration?