# Webview opens Youtube but video does not play

Tags: android, webview, youtube

n my application I have used web view to YouTube link. The link opens, but when I click on the video link in Youtube site nothing happens. It does not show any error or exception but it doesn't play video either

etc : http://www.youtube.com/user/XXXX

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/user/XXXX"));
```

The best approach is to launch native player to play youtube file or refer this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1uvoM2bqKBcJ%3awww.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-play-video-and-audio-android%20play%20video%20file%20in%20android&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&source=www.google.com) to play in media player.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. but I want to do is run from within the application. How can I do without leaving the application in a WebView?

Comment: try the link in my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506576/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-webview-in-android

Comment: In this connection there is only an example for one video. If you notice a user page, I want to run the desired video link

Comment: I'm having the same problem here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036627/web-view-to-youtube-opens-but-the-video-does-not-play

Comment: Friends Do not have an answer?