# How can i play videos in webview android?

Tags: android, html, video, webview

Since im quite new to Java and Android apps, i had to ask this question because im working for  10 hours and couldnt achive anything. I made a full screen web app in eclipse but i cant see videos in there. Here's my codes:

Tarim.java

```
package com.tarim.tarimvideo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.tarim.tarimvideo.util.SystemUiHider;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Tarim extends Activity {

private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;
private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;
private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;
private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tarim);

    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.tarayici);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8SCqLkHDqw");


    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView,
            HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView
                                .animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    }); 

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
    // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
    // are available.
    delayedHide(100);
}
View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
    }
};
private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
}   
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tarim.tarimvideo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.tarim.tarimvideo.Tarim"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity.tarim.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".Tarim" >

<!--
     The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc.
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!--
     This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/tarayici"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Please note that im in this Java thing just for 10 hours, so if you can explain me as much as simple, it would be so great.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it is possible in a WebView without the assistance of flash. Please look at this: [Youtube in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292086/play-youtube-video-in-webview) (used for reference). And look at this for a flash demo: [Flash demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506576/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-webview-in-android). Lastly [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) might also be helpful, it is Android's YouTube API.

Comment: Thanx for fast reply GLaDOS but as i said in my post, im quite new to developing something. ım just trying to understand where to put this code in my .java file.

Comment: 'Thanx for fast reply GLaDOS but as i said in my post, im quite new to developing something. Can you tell me where to put this code in my .java file?

Comment: @KayahanKahriman the code from the second link would go in the Activity (likely in the onCreate method) you are using to display your video.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a .html file in your SDCARD which contain your video link.(mention video link as `content:\\`).and load that .html file to the webview.

Comment: Can you be more spesific please a4android?